# How do I expose a TaskExecutor over JMX in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot

A similar question was asked and answered in the spring forums when using XML configuration:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/723982-i-cant-figure-out-how-to-expose-task-executor-vai-jmx?p=724001#post724001

I'd like to avoid using XML. I'm using Spring Boot 1.1.4, and have included spring-boot-actuator. My Application class looks like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
@EnableConfigurationProperties
public class Application {
    // ...

    // this method is never called
    @Bean
    protected MBeanExporter mbeanExporter() {
        MBeanExporter exporter = new MBeanExporter();
        Map<String,Object> beans = new HashMap<>();
        beans.put("org.springframework.boot:type=executor,name=taskExecutor", taskExecutor());
        exporter.setBeans(beans);
        return exporter;
    }

    @Bean
    protected AsyncTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(200);
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your `mbeanExporter()` method is not being called? If so, what happens if you set `spring.jmx.enabled=false` in `application.properties`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably another bean called "mbeanExporter" overriding yours. I think the idiom is wrong anyway though a - what you probably need is an `MBeanInfoAssembler` (even if you have to plug it into an `MBeanExporter` with a different bean name).

Comment: Thanks Dave, I changed the name to myMbeanExporter() and it was called. With only that change all works as expected, the properties of the ThreadPoolTaskExecutor are properly exposed over JMX.